# Javascript Object output to Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

This is a very very simple question, but for some reason I'm stuck with it.

How can I take an object like:

```
var billionaire = {
    "10" : {
        "firstName" : "Steve",
        "lastName" : "Jobs",
        "company" : "Apple"
    },
    "11" : {
        "firstName" : "Bill",
        "lastName" : "Gates",
        "company" : "Microsoft"
    },
    "12" : {
        "firstName" : "Warren",
        "lastName" : "Buffet",
        "company" : "Berkshire Hathaway"
    }
};
```

And Output it into an array like this using pure javascript

```
var arr = [
    "Steve",
    "Bill",
    "Warren"
];
```

I do just need the firstName in the array. Thanks for your help and sorry for the easy question.

Comment: what effort have you made?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
var arr = Object.keys(billionaire).map(function(k){ return billionaire[k].firstName });
```

Comment: What benefits do you get out of using the `map` over iterating the keys in a for loop? `for (var key in billionaire) { billionaire[key].firstName; }`

Comment: @zLan No other benefit than just having one expression and not polluting the current scope (for that effect you'd have to wrap your loop in a closure or use the new `let` keyword).